# Running tests with localStorage

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

i have followed [this](http://yeoman.io/codelab/local-storage.html) tutorial from Codelab and yeoman. When implemented right you are using local storage to store the TodoList. I have problems with setting up with my tests, to test if this works. This is what i've got so far:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('yeoTodoApp'), module('LocalStorageModule'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should add items to the list', function () {
    var beforeLength = scope.todos.length;
    scope.todo = 'Test 1';
    scope.addTodo();
    var afterLength = scope.todos.length;
    expect(afterLength-beforeLength).toBe(1);
  });
it('should add items to the list then remove', function () {
    var beforeLength = scope.todos.length;
    scope.todo = 'Test 1';
    scope.addTodo();
    scope.removeTodo(0);
    var afterLength = scope.todos.length;
    expect(afterLength-beforeLength).toBe(0);
  });

});
```

The error i get is

> line 12  col 68  '$httpBackend' is defined but never used.
>   });

How would i write my unit tests to sit the local storage?

Comment: your error is a jslint error, just remove $httpBackend from your function arguments...

Comment: Thank you for you help. If i remove $httpBackend from my function arguments i get the same tests as i did without localstorage

`Controller: MainCtrl should add items to the list then remove FAILED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your setup is correct now (after you removed $httpBackend from the arguments list)

```
Controller: MainCtrl should add items to the list then remove FAILED
```

this error is a simple test error, which means that your code somewhere doesnt work as expected (your second test fails)

i for myself would check todos length, and not the result of a mathematical operation.

i would write your tests the test like this:

```
it('should add items to the list then remove', function () {
  scope.todo = 'Test 1';
  expect(scope.todos.length).toBe(0);
  scope.addTodo();
  expect(scope.todos.length).toBe(1);
  scope.removeTodo(0);
  expect(scope.todos.length).toBe(0);
});
```

you use jasmine as a test-tool. jasmine logs on errors exactly which expectation fails, so you should get something like

```
expect '1' to be '0'
```

go from there!

Answer (score 2):

I think at the moment the idea is kind of mocking your local storage:

> Write unit tests
>
> For an extra challenge, revisit unit testing in Step 8 and consider
>   how you might update your tests now that the code is using local
>   storage.
>
> Tip: It's not a straight forward answer and involves knowing about
>   mock services. Check out Unit Testing Best Practices in AngularJS,
>   specifically the Mocking Services and Modules in AngularJS section.

Things may have changed since this question was asked. Anyhow, here is my solution:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('mytodoyoappApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope,
    localStorage, store;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope:scope
      // place here mocked dependencies
    });

    /*mock the localStorageService*/
    store={};

    localStorage = {
      set: function(key, value) {
        store[key] = value;
      },
      get: function(key) {
        return store[key];
      }
    };

  }));

  it('should check the list length', function () {
    expect(MainCtrl.todos.length).toBe(0);
  });

  it('should add items to the list', function () {
    MainCtrl.todoadded = 'Test 1';
    MainCtrl.addTodo();
    expect(MainCtrl.todos.length).toBe(1);
  });

  it('should add then remove an item from the list', function () {
    MainCtrl.todoadded = 'Test 2';
    MainCtrl.addTodo();
    MainCtrl.removeTodo(0);
    expect(MainCtrl.todos.length).toBe(0);
  });

  it('should check that the localstorage is undefined before being set', function() {
    var a=localStorage.get('todos');
    expect(a).toBeUndefined();
  });

  it('should set and get the localstorage', function() {
    localStorage.set('todos', ['Test 3']);
    var a=localStorage.get('todos');
    expect(a).toEqual(['Test 3']);

    localStorage.set('todos', ['Test 4']);
    var b=localStorage.get('todos');
    expect(b).toEqual(['Test 4']); 
  });
});
```