# Yeoman's Angular.js codelab - fixing the tests

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, phantomjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I complete the tutorial from [this codelab](http://yeoman.io/codelab/local-storage.html), and as suggested tried to fix the errors on the unit tests.
But i don't know how to fix this error. I already took a look at this question:[running-tests-with-localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337046/running-tests-with-localstorage) but it does not address my problem.

Here's my test file:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(function(){
    module('mytodoApp'),
    module('LocalStorageModule')
  });

  var MainCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should have no items to start', function () {
    expect(scope.todos.length).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

And here is the console output:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux) Controller: MainCtrl should have no items to start FAILED
        Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mytodoApp due to:
        Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module LocalStorageModule due to:
        Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'LocalStorageModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/nomod?p0=LocalStorageModule
            at /home/ubuntu/mytodo/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1613
            at ensure (/home/ubuntu/mytodo/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1535)
            at module (/home/ubuntu/mytodo/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1823)
            at /home/ubuntu/mytodo/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3781
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=LocalStorageModule&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'LocalStorageModule'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DLocalStorageModule%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A1613%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A1535)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A1823)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3781
            at /home/ubuntu/mytodo/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3810
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=mytodoApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20Failed%20to%20instantiate%20module%20LocalStorageModule%20due%20to%3A%0AError%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'LocalStorageModule'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DLocalStorageModule%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A1613%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A1535)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A1823)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3781%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DLocalStorageModule%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520Module%2520'LocalStorageModule'%2520is%2520not%2520available!%2520You%2520either%2520misspelled%2520the%2520module%2520name%2520or%2520forgot%2520to%2520load%2520it.%2520If%2520registering%2520a%2520module%2520ensure%2520that%2520you%2520specify%2520the%2520dependencies%2520as%2520the%2520second%2520argument.%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.16%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DLocalStorageModule%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fbase%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.js%253F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%253A1613%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520ensure%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fbase%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.js%253F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%253A1535)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520module%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fbase%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.js%253F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%253A1823)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fbase%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.js%253F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%253A3781%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3810
            at /home/ubuntu/mytodo/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3810
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.04 secs / 0.006 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

UPDATE: Added the answer.

Here's my karma.conf.js file, fixed. Had to add the module angular-local-storage.js to the list of files.

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-sortable/sortable.js',
      'bower_components/angular-local-storage/angular-local-storage.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
```

Comment: The error states that it can't load the `LocalStorageModule` module, you have included the file that contains this module in to your karma config, right?

Comment: You are correct. I totally forgot to add that module in the Karma.conf.js file. Please post it as an answer so i can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `karama.conf.js` file contains a `files` array. When testing, make sure the files containing all of your dependent modules are inserted in to the array:

```
files: [
    /* file paths */
]
```

One other cool thing is that the file section supports [patterns](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/files.html). One way to avoid this problem in the future is to put all your modules or required scripts in to one place or under one common folder and use a pattern to load them all:

```
files: [
    /* or whatever other pattern you want to use */
    '/myProject/scripts/vendor/*.min.js',
    '/myProject/scripts/modules/*.min.js',
    /* the use of ** will search any child folder for the file pattern */
    '/myProject/scripts/tests/**/*.js'
]
```